# call test scripts from main driver script perl

Tags: perl

I have a main setup script which sets up the test env and stores data in some variables:

```
package main;
use Test::Harness;

our $foo, $xyz, $pqr;
($foo, $xyz, $pqr) = &subroutinesetup();
# ^ here

@test_files = glob "t/*";
print "Executing test @test\n";
runtests(@test_files);
```

In the test folder I have a testsuite (t/testsuite1.t, testsuite2.t etc.).
How can I access the value of $foo inside the testsuite1.t?

```
package main;
use Test::More;
$actual = getActual();
is($foo, $actual, passfoor);
#   ^ here

done_testing();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.  Even the test scripts. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Storable](https://metacpan.org/module/Storable) to store data in first script and retrieve it from other.

`main.pl`

```
  ($foo, $xyz, $pqr) = &subroutinesetup();
  store ($foo, "/home/chankey/testsuite.$$") or die "could not store";
  system("perl", "testsuite.pl", $$) == 0 or die "error";
```

`testsuite.pl`

```
my $parentpid = shift;
my $ref = retrieve("/home/chankey/testsuite.$parentpid") or die "couldn't retrieve";
print Dumper $ref;
```

You've received the `$foo` in `$ref`. Now use it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can't share a variable directly, because a new Perl process is started for each test file.

As noted in the documentation of [Test::Harness](http://p3rl.org/Test%3a%3aHarness), you should switch to [TAP::Harness](http://p3rl.org/TAP%3a%3aHarness). It's more flexible: for example, it provides the `test_args` mechanism to pass arguments to test scripts.

```
$ cat 1.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use TAP::Harness;

my $harness = 'TAP::Harness'->new({
                  test_args => [ qw( propagate secret ) ]
              });

$harness->runtests('1.t');
__END__

$ cat 1.t
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Test::More;

my %args = @ARGV;
is($args{propagate}, 'secret', 'propagated');
done_testing();
```